# Mapping windows directory to docker container by absolute path

Tags: windows, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to map windows folder to docker container. Path is C:/myfolder.
Using -v command line option works fine, but I'd like to do it using dockerfile.

`RUN --mount=source="myfolder",target="/workspace/myfolder"`

This works ok for local folder, but not if I specify an absolute path

`RUN --mount=source="C:\myfolder",target="/workspace/myfolder"`

This returns error "failed to compute cache key: "/c:myfolder" not found: not found"

I tried to use different path syntaxes, such as //c/myfolder and others, but always encounter error in docker build. Same result with relative paths such as "../myfolder", etc. What is the correct way of doing this?